# How to turn on the intelligence for the UITextField in iPhone

Tags: iphone

When you type something in iPhoneSearchBar it shows the text with the help of intelligence. I want to turn on the same for a UITextField. So how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [tableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848) sample code on the iPhone Dev. Center.  It uses a `UISearchBar`, `UISearchBarDelegate`, `UISearchDisplayController`, and `UISearchDisplayDelegate`.

**iPhone Dev. Center links:**
[UISearchBar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007529-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1)
[UISearchBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate)
[UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchDisplayController)
[UISearchDisplayDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchDisplayDelegate)